# Android SQLite Query

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

So I do not have any issues inserting information into my table, but when I try to query my database, I seem to have issues retrieving it. I am new to SQLite and databases in general so maybe my understanding is different. Here are the declarations for my constants:

```
    public static abstract class TableInfo implements BaseColumns
{
    //User Table
    public static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";
    public static final String USER_PASS = "user_pass";
    public static final String USER_FNAME = "user_fname";
    public static final String USER_LNAME = "user_lname";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "current_users";
    public static final String USER_TABLE = "user_info";

    //Message Table
    public static final String MESSAGE_ID = "msg_id";
    public static final String RECEIVER_ID = "receiver_id";
    public static final String SENDER_ID = "sender_id";
    public static final String MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String STATUS = "status";
    public static final String MSG_TABLE = "msg_info";
```

This is my query string to create the table (which works)

```
 public String CREATE_MSG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.MSG_TABLE +
        " ( " + TableData.TableInfo.MESSAGE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + TableData.TableInfo.RECEIVER_ID + " TEXT, "
        + TableData.TableInfo.SENDER_ID + " TEXT, "
        + TableData.TableInfo.MESSAGE + " TEXT, "
        + TableData.TableInfo.STATUS + " INTEGER);";
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb){
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    Log.d("Database operations", "Table1 created");
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_MSG_TABLE);
    Log.d("Database operations", "Table2 created");

}
```

This is the method I use to query the database for my information. It is a messaging application so I want the receiver_id and message:

```
public Cursor getInformationMsgTable(DatabaseOperations dop) {
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor CR = SQ.rawQuery("SELECT "
            +  TableData.TableInfo.RECEIVER_ID + ","
            +  TableData.TableInfo.SENDER_ID + ","
            +  TableData.TableInfo.MESSAGE + ","
            +  TableData.TableInfo.STATUS
            + " FROM " + TableData.TableInfo.MSG_TABLE,null);
    return CR;
}
```

And finally, this what I do when I return with the cursor:

```
 private void loadMessages()
    {
    DatabaseOperations DOP = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
    //The cursor will iterate through the DB
    Cursor CR = DOP.getInformationMsgTable(DOP);
    if(CR.getCount() > 0)
    {
        CR.moveToFirst();

        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]
            {
                    TableData.TableInfo.RECEIVER_ID,
                    TableData.TableInfo.MESSAGE
            };
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
            {
                    R.id.userNameFromDB,
                    R.id.messageInfoDB
            };
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                CTX,
                R.layout.item_layout,
                CR,
                fromFieldNames,
                toViewIDs);
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friendsLV);
        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }
}
```

I have inserted multiple rows into the table, I log everytime I do. But the error I get is "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist", which is referring to the receiver_id column. Any thoughts? I find it strange that it cuts out the part before the '_'. Also, when the table is empty, I can use the load message function and not have any issues, but when I add a row to the table THEN query the table, I get issues and errors. Thanks. EDIT: I copied the wrong function, it is corrected now.

A trace as requested: 
04-07 23:14:57.850  32315-32315/com.example.andy.justalk D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-07 23:14:57.852  32315-32315/com.example.andy.justalk E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.andy.justalk, PID: 32315
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
            at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:172)
            at android.widget.CursorAdapter.(CursorAdapter.java:120)
            at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:52)
            at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:78)
            at com.example.andy.justalk.FriendsList.loadMessages(FriendsList.java:72)
            at com.example.andy.justalk.FriendsList.access$000(FriendsList.java:17)
            at com.example.andy.justalk.FriendsList$1.onClick(FriendsList.java:35)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: Could you post your complete logcat trace about this error?

Comment: I don't have extensive experience with SQLite, but I don't see a `;` at the end of your select.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not make a difference @smskelley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and define tables as you wish, but if you will have to use the table via a CursorAdapter that won't work without a tweak.

CursorAdapter: The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

You must always issue a select col1 as _id ... to work.

So it's recommended to use _id in the table schema.

Comment: I thought that was the issue as well but it I have a column named msg_id and it is an Integer primary key. I included that in my query just now and I still get an error, is that what you meant?

Comment: Nope. You must have a column name with "_id" name or you can make some changes in select query. can you just post me select query?

Comment: Cursor CR = SQ.rawQuery("SELECT "
            +  TableData.TableInfo.RECEIVER_ID + ","
            +  TableData.TableInfo.SENDER_ID + ","
            +  TableData.TableInfo.MESSAGE + ","
            +  TableData.TableInfo.STATUS
            + " FROM " + TableData.TableInfo.MSG_TABLE,null);

Comment: Cursor CR = SQ.rawQuery("SELECT " + TableData.TableInfo.MESSAGE_ID +" AS _id, " + TableData.TableInfo.RECEIVER_ID + "," + TableData.TableInfo.SENDER_ID + "," + TableData.TableInfo.MESSAGE + "," + TableData.TableInfo.STATUS + " FROM " + TableData.TableInfo.MSG_TABLE,null);

Comment: Thank you so much, I just changed the column name of msg_id to _id. Thank you for the help